# Encoding floats in a dictionary using custom python JSON encoder

Tags: python, json

Here's a simple JSON encoder that convert float values to string:

```
class NestedEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    '''
    A JSON Encoder that converts floats/decimals to strings and allows nested objects
    '''

    def default(self, obj):

        if isinstance(obj, float) or obj.__class__.__name__ == "float32":
            return self.floattostr(obj)
        elif obj.__class__.__name__ == "type":
            return str(obj)
        elif hasattr(obj, 'repr_json'):
            return obj.repr_json()
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

    def floattostr(self,o,_inf=float('Inf'), _neginf=-float('-Inf'),nan_str="None"):
        if o != o:
            text = nan_str
        elif o == _inf:
            text = 'Infinity'
        elif o == _neginf:
            text = '-Infinity'
        else:
            return o.__repr__()

        return text
```

Now here's two tests. The first creates a Infinity valued float and encodes it using the custom encoder. Test passes.

```
def test_inf():
    inf = float('Inf')
    as_json = json.dumps(inf,cls=NestedEncoder)
    assert as_json == "Infinity"
```

The second test does the same but puts the float in a dictionary:

```
def test_inf_dic():
    inf = float('Inf')
    as_json = json.dumps({'key':inf},cls=NestedEncoder)
    assert as_json == "{'key':'Infinity'}"
```

OUTPUT:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________________________ test_inf_dic _________________________________

    def test_inf_dic():
        inf = float('Inf')
        as_json = json.dumps({'key':inf},cls=NestedEncoder)
>       assert as_json == "{'key':'Infinity'}"
E       assert '{"key": Infinity}' == "{'key':'Infinity'}"
E         - {"key": Infinity}
E         ?  ^   ^ ^
E         + {'key':'Infinity'}
E         ?  ^   ^ ^        +
```

EDIT:

The custom encoder only gets called for the first test, not the second.

Comment: Python2.7 returns "float" for `float('Inf').__class__.__name__`, so it won't match your first conditional. You are also trying to compare a string to a dict in your test.

Comment: @jordanm i fixed the assertion. See issue with encoding Infinity. 
The `float('Inf').__class__.__name__` issue you pointed to isn't relevant since it's an OR conditional

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that your custom function is not getting called during your test. The reason for this is explained in the docs:

> If specified, default should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON encodable version of the object or raise a TypeError. If not specified, TypeError is raised.

Since `float` is an object that it already knows how to serialized, it is not called. For `float` serialization, you can override the `encode` function.

Comment: Thanks but if that was the case why does the first test passes?

Comment: @gidim `json.dumps(float('Inf'))` by default returns a string 'Infinity'. I am not sure why that is, but I tested it in ipython. I also tested your class and function by inserting a breakpoint that was never hit.

Comment: @gidim Looks like according to the json spec, `Infinity` can only be a value, which can only be inside of an object or array: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159

Comment: I think the spec doesn't allow Infinity at all, that's why i'm trying to convert it to a string. The first test does hit the NestedEncoder the second doesn't. Even if dic is supported it should get called on its values no?

Comment: @jordanm How does one go about overriding `encode`..?